# Rails: Why does my route enforce an ending with a dot id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is a small portion of my rake route:

```
   new_word GET    /words/add(.:format)                        words#new
create_word POST   /words(.:format)                            words#create
      words GET    /words/:category(.:format)                  words#index
  edit_word GET    /words/:category/:word_param/edit(.:format) words#edit {:word_param=>/[a-zA-Z]+/}
       word GET    /words/:category/:word_param(.:format)      words#show {:word_param=>/[a-zA-Z]+/}
            PATCH  /words/:category/:word_param(.:format)      words#update {:word_param=>/[a-zA-Z]+/}
            PUT    /words/:category/:word_param(.:format)      words#update {:word_param=>/[a-zA-Z]+/}
            DELETE /words/:category/:word_param(.:format)      words#destroy {:word_param=>/[a-zA-Z]+/}
```

So basically, my intended route is something like

> localhost:3000/words/all/word

But I get something like

> localhost:3000/words/all/word.8 # obviously the dot id syndrome

And here is an example of some of the extra parameters I pass in the paths/url (in my index.html.erb):

```
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', word_path(word, category: word.category,word_param:word.name)  %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_word_path(word, category: word.category, word_param:word.name) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', word_path(word, category: word.category, word_param:word.name), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Edit: TLDR; Like several other posts, it was the path helper function and I've had trouble using the documentation to reach the answer. (I can't even find it)

Comment: Can you add the helper you used to get this URL?

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! I just posted a few examples. My thought is anything could be wrong... I just randomly guessed how to pass in those parameters lol.

Comment: Yep, that's the issue... Guess I have to figure out how to fix those parameters. My first question is how to even find the source code or the api for these path helpers...I swear I did that before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're accidentally passing an object to the optional `(.:format)` part of the route. This is why the object's ID is showing up after a period - that's exactly how a format (`.html`, `.css`, etc.) is supposed to be displayed in a URL.

Take a look at how you're calling your routes and make sure you're not inadvertently passing in one too many things.

EDIT: Yes, now that you've added the links, this is what you're doing. Look at the `word_path` call - you're passing three variables there - `word`, `word.category`, and `word.name`. You've explicitly assigned two of those to the `:category` and `:word_param` spots in your route. The third, extra variable is automatically being assigned to `:format` because that's the only variable left in the route.

Try these instead:

```
word_path(category: word.category, word_param: word.name)
edit_word_path(category: word.category, word_param: word.name)
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that's exactly what's happening with the paths. I need to figure out how to fix this

Comment: Just don't pass that additional first `word` variable in your `word_path` and `edit_word_path` calls and it should be fine.

Comment: thanks. any clue how i can look at the documentation for that path helper? im having trouble finding it

Comment: Strange, I have another one in my edit.html.erb but that one doesn't experience it once I removed the one in index.html... Oh well, it makes sense since a link should only require the parameters, not the object itself.

Comment: Well, there's the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). If you want to dig into the code it's in ActionDispatch::Routing somewhere.